# replace match to a back reference with a string in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to come up with a sed script to modify the constructors in a couple hundred php files from php4 style to php5 style. I'm making some progress, but I'm having a problem with getting the back references out of sed. Here is an example file :

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    function Dashboard()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
    }
}
```

The goal is to grab the class name from the first line (which will have 0 or 1 blank lines between it and the

This works as expected:

```
sed -En '/^class\ ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ {
    n;H;x;n;H;x;'s/Dash/Derp/';P
}' dashtest.php
```

Giving the output:

```
function Derpboard()
```

But why is this not replacing Dashboard with __construct?:

```
sed -En '/^class\ ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ {
    n;H;x;n;H;x;'s/\1/__construct/';P
}' dashtest.php
```

Any other advice on this would be welcome. My intention is to wrap this in a shell script that is making a bunch of other changes migrating from an ancient version of codeIgnitor php framework the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'` you have just before `s/…` exits single-quote mode, causing the whole `s/\1/__construct/` (up to the next `'`) to be parsed as *unquoted* by your shell. In this mode, `\1` gets translated to just `1`, so *sed* ends up receiving `s/1/__construct/`.

Note that this would not work *anyway*, because backreferences in POSIX regexes used by *sed* can only refer to groups within the *same* regexp, and *sed* has no special syntax for using previous matches.

You would need something more advanced – for example:

```
perl -pe '
    if (/^class (\w+)/) {
        $class = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^\}$/) {
        $class = "";
    }
    elsif ($class and /function \Q$class\E\(/) {
        s//function __construct(/;
    }
'
```

Comment: I see. I was hoping to hone my rather lacking sed-fu with this task, but it looks like I'll go for brushing up on Perl instead. This example is only the first of several modifications that I'll need to make, and I will definitely need to store some matches for later use. Thank you.